# Using XSLT to sort elements that will match the correct schema XSD

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xsd, schema

I want to do something like this [Can you transform unordered xml to match an xsd:sequence order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771462/can-you-transform-unordered-xml-to-match-an-xsdsequence-order) bu a little more complex than that. For example:

```
<person> 
   <addressList>
        <address>
            <city>Chicago</city>
            <state>IL</state>
            <zip>41111</zip>
        </address>
        <address>
            <state>MO</state>
            <zip>64521</zip>
            <city>Kansas City</city>
        </address>
   </addressList>  
   <lastname>The BFG</lastname> 
   <firstname>1234567890</firstname>
</person>
```

I don't have control in the schema so this sould match the schema, but when I try to deserialize throw an error... so the solution is use XSLT to transform this to match XSD format. I just want to get the same input but in different order for instance something like this:

Note that City in the 2nd address, first name, and last name was move.

```
<person>  
   <lastname>The BFG</lastname> 
   <firstname>1234567890</firstname>
   <addressList>
        <address>
            <city>Chicago</city>
            <state>IL</state>
            <zip>41111</zip>
        </address>
        <address>
            <city>Kansas City</city>
            <state>MO</state>
            <zip>64521</zip>
        </address>
   </addressList> 
</person>
```

Comment: This was very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800593/transform-xml-into-specified-ordering-dtd-xsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the previous link ([Transform XML into specified ordering (DTD -> XSD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800593/transform-xml-into-specified-ordering-dtd-xsd)), the only changes we have to make are the xml inside of XSLT document and the name of the root (Top for person) and the new XSLT look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:my="my-namespace" 
   exclude-result-prefixes="my">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <my:person>  
       <my:lastname/> 
       <my:firstname/>
       <my:addressList>
            <my:address>
                <my:city/>
                <my:state/>
                <my:zip/>
            </my:address>
       </my:addressList> 
    </my:person>
  <xsl:template match="my:*">
    <xsl:param name="source"/>
    <xsl:variable name="current-lookup-elem" select="current()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$source/*[name()=local-name($current-lookup-elem)]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$current-lookup-elem/*">
          <xsl:with-param name="source" select="current()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/person">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/my:*">
      <xsl:with-param name="source" select="/"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="firstname|lastname"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="addressList"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="address">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="city"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="state"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="zip"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<person>
    <addressList>
        <address>
            <city>Chicago</city>
            <state>IL</state>
            <zip>41111</zip>
        </address>
        <address>
            <state>MO</state>
            <zip>64521</zip>
            <city>Kansas City</city>
        </address>
    </addressList>
    <lastname>The BFG</lastname>
    <firstname>1234567890</firstname>
</person>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<person>
   <lastname>The BFG</lastname>
   <firstname>1234567890</firstname>
   <addressList>
      <address>
         <city>Chicago</city>
         <state>IL</state>
         <zip>41111</zip>
      </address>
      <address>
         <city>Kansas City</city>
         <state>MO</state>
         <zip>64521</zip>
      </address>
   </addressList>
</person>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule (when not overriden) matches every node "as-is".
2. We only override the identity template for elements, the order of whose children needs to be changed in the output/
3. To process and output nodes in order that is different from their document order, a sequence of `xsl:apply-templates` instructions needs to be specified, that explicitly specifies the desired new order of processing.